# Error:Execution failed for task when using MQTT dependencies ...paho.android.service:1.0.2

Tags: android-studio, mqtt, dex, mosquitto, paho

I have just started using MQTT protocol with **Android Studio**. Using mosquitto broker. The app built successfully with Android Studio if i remove this dependience from grandle :
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2  , 
but the app dosn't start.

When i compile including the string :
complile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2' 
the errore is :

*Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Landroid/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoVersionImpl;*

I tried many different alternatives but no one worked good.
I have no any ideas

Answer (score 1):

Try to modify your app's `build.gradle` file (`dependencies` section) like this:

```
compile 'org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3:1.0.2'
compile('org.eclipse.paho:org.eclipse.paho.android.service:1.0.2') {
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
}
```

The error is throwing (maybe) because you are trying to 'include' the `support-v4` module more than once.

Comment: I got the "Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'." error when building, and yes, it was because I used androidx, and without this exlusion classes were duplicated through the support depency.